# Are there pronouns missing: "such as are"?

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

> In particular,
>   the rights provided for under Arts 8, 9, 10 and 11 are subject to legal restrictions
>   **such as ♦ are**:
>
> > . . . necessary in a democratic society in the interests of national security or
> >     public safety

1. Shouldn't there be pronouns at ♦ (my own addition), like "those that"? If not, how and why not?
2. Are there any grammatical terms that describe the issues here?

Source: p 47, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 1):

The insertion you suggest could be helpful but here it is implied. I think it is the style adopted by Gary Slapper, perhaps related to the ways lawyers write and/or speak. In any case, it is **not** misleading and it **is** shorter, so to be commended!

Comment: I think that you're correct that this construction is specific to legal writing. Pronouns could be ambiguous, so I think legalese avoids them.